# Игра некорректно работает после компиляции

Tags: c#, windows, unity3d

Недавно написал игру на unity. Решил скомпилировать под ПК. После компиляции всё работало прекрасно, но пропала фоновая музыка, хотя в редакторе во время игры трек проигрывался. Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: как ты воспроизводил звук? скорей всего файл не попал в ассеты.

Comment: Через объект audio source

Comment: а в коде как запускаешь? у меня была схожая проблема с изображениями когда я открывал напрямую из файла. попробуй через `Resources.Load`

Comment: У меня без кода работало. Это была просто музыка в фоне

Comment: попробуй перенести файл в папку `Resources`. то есть "Assets\Resources\file.mp3"

Comment: Общий совет: если билд работает некорректно, сразу иди в логи. По умолчанию юнити пишет сообщения в лог-файл, который в твоём случае **скорее всего** где-то здесь: `C:\Users\ТвойЮзер\AppData\LocalLow\DefaultCompany\ИмяПроектаЮнити\Player.log`. В твоём случае скорее всего не найден файл, запись об этом должна быть в логе.